# Using the "This" Pointer in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, this

I've been reading about the "this" pointer on various sites (e.g. the MSDN manuals) and understand its basic uses -- returning a copy your own object or using a pointer of it for returns/comparison.

But I came across this statement:

```
  // Return an object that defines its own operator[] that will access the data.
  // The temp object is very trivial and just allows access to the data via 
  // operator[]
  VectorDeque2D_Inner_Set<T> operator[](unsigned int first_index) { 
    return VectorDeque2D_Inner_Set<T>(*this, first_index);
  }
```

What does that do?  Does it somehow increment the this operator, and if so, why??

(This comes from an example I was given on stack overflow, so there may be mistakes in the syntax.  Let me know if a bigger chunk is necessary, I can paste more code in.)

---

**EDIT 1**
Here's the entire listing, for more info.  The function is near the bottom of the class.  Note I renamed the variable from x to index and renamed the templated inner class.  I forgot to put the typecast to the templated inner-class, which I have added in this update.

Any ideas now?

```
template <typename T>
class Container
{
private:
    // ...


public:

    // Proxy object used to provide the second brackets
    template <typename T>
    class OperatorBracketHelper
    {
        Container<T> & parent;
        size_t firstIndex;
    public:
        OperatorBracketHelper(Container<T> & Parent, size_t FirstIndex) : parent(Parent), firstIndex(FirstIndex) {}

        // This is the method called for the "second brackets"
        T & operator[](size_t SecondIndex)
        {
            // Call the parent GetElement method which will actually retrieve the element
            return parent.GetElement(firstIndex, SecondIndex);
        }

    }

    // This is the method called for the "first brackets"
    OperatorBracketHelper<T> operator[](size_t FirstIndex)
    {
        // Return a proxy object that "knows" to which container it has to ask the element
        // and which is the first index (specified in this call)
        return OperatorBracketHelper<T>(*this, FirstIndex);
    }

    T & GetElement(size_t FirstIndex, size_t SecondIndex)
    {
        // Here the actual element retrieval is done
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Where was the example given, what is the context?

Comment: Although the code may compile, it looks like it is wrong.

Comment: I've added the full listing now.  Granted this wasn't full code, just an idea someone on here gave to flesh out, about making a 2D wrapped vector/deque object accessible with double brackets ("[][]") via an intermediate inner object.  My apologies for forgetting the typecast in my original expression and for not putting the full listing, but at least I had the sense to ask if it was necessary! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [**this**](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr035.htm) keyword basically is a pointer reference to the object that it's currently in use. In C++, **this** is a pointer, so to dereference it, use `*this`.

So, this code,

```
return VectorDeque2D_Inner_Set<T>(*this, index);
```

returns a new VectorDeque2D_Inner_Set by passing a dereferenced of itself (since the constructor wants the reference of the object and not the pointer address).

This method,

```
 // This is the method called for the "first brackets"
    OperatorBracketHelper<T> operator[](size_t FirstIndex)
    {
        // Return a proxy object that "knows" to which container it has to ask the element
        // and which is the first index (specified in this call)
        return OperatorBracketHelper<T>(*this, FirstIndex);
    }
```

just passed a dereferenced `self` to the constructor `OperatorBracketHelper` as it requires a `Container&` as parameter.

Comment: Make sense.  What's the lifespan of the new object created, since it was returned from a function?  Is there any worries there?

Comment: As long as the object exists in memory (and not garbage collected, this should be fine). Oh yes, in C++, manage your pointers carefully as you don't want to have `Segmentation Faults`. In your example, you shouldn't worry at all, as you are getting OperatorBracketHelper from Container (which in essence means that Container exists in memory).

Comment: Thanks, good info.  I'm picking your answer.  Everyone gave good responses, but I felt yours was the most detailed.

Comment: Glad to have been of help. Last time I did C++ was in 2006. :-)

Answer (score 5):

The `*` operator dereferences the `this` pointer. This is necessary because the method being called ( constructor `OperatorBracketHelper(Container<T> & Parent, size_t FirstIndex)` ) requires a reference rather than a pointer.

Is this a fail pattern? I dunno. It smells to me on an instinctive level, but I can't find anything directly wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

it creates an instance of OpBracketHelper with the a reference to the current Container as its parent member (*this passes in a reference to the container object to the constructor)

My only concern would be about lifetimes of the Container and the helper object. I would be tempted to use shared_ptr rather than a reference